# Errror submitting a form-The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect-Spring DAO

Tags: java, mysql, spring

At first there was an issue of not identifying some bean properties which were named with camel cases and underscores. So I removed those and regenerated the entity classes. Although that issue is resolved now it gives an error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" with HTTP Status 400 when I submit the following form. Though there are similar questions I couldn't find the answer for my one.

**JSP page**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form action="addDistrict" method="POST" modelAttribute="district">
                    <form:select class="form-control" style="border-radius: 0px" placeholder="ADA Zone" path="adaid">
                        <c:forEach items="${adas}" var="result">
                            <form:option value="${result.adaid}">${result.adaname}</form:option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                    <form:input path="districtid" type="hidden"></form:input>
                    <form:input path="districtname" placeholder="District Name:"></form:input>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-app"><i class="material-icons md-18" style="font-size:1.0em;">mode_edit</i></button>
                </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
package edu.cdms.project.dao.impl;

import edu.cdms.project.dao.BranchDAO;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ascenter;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.District;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ds;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class BranchDAOImpl implements BranchDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }


    public ArrayList<Adazone> getADAList(){
        Session session=getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query namedQuery=session.getNamedQuery("Adazone.findAll");
        ArrayList<Adazone> adaZones=(ArrayList<Adazone>) namedQuery.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return adaZones;
    }


    public boolean addDistrict(District district) {
        Session session=getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(district);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
package edu.cdms.project.service;

import edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ascenter;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.District;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ds;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface BranchService {

    public ArrayList<Adazone> getADAList();

    public boolean addDistrict(District district);

}
```

**Implemented Service**

```
package edu.cdms.project.service.impl;

import edu.cdms.project.dao.BranchDAO;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ascenter;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.District;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ds;
import edu.cdms.project.service.BranchService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class BranchServiceImpl implements BranchService{

    @Autowired
    private BranchDAO branchDAO;


    public ArrayList<Adazone> getADAList() {
        return branchDAO.getADAList();
    }

    public boolean addDistrict(District district){
        return branchDAO.addDistrict(district);
    }

}
```

**DAO**

```
package edu.cdms.project.dao;

import edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ascenter;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.District;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ds;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface BranchDAO {

    public ArrayList<Adazone> getADAList();

    public boolean addDistrict(District district);


}
```

**Implemented DAO**

```
    package edu.cdms.project.contrl;

import edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ailist;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ascenter;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.District;
import edu.cdms.project.orm.Ds;
import edu.cdms.project.service.BranchService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BranchController {

    @Autowired
    private BranchService branchService;


        @RequestMapping(value = "/addDistrict", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addDistrict(@Valid District district, ModelMap map){

        branchService.addDistrict(district);
        ArrayList<Adazone> adaZones=branchService.getADAList();
        map.addAttribute("adas", adaZones);
        map.addAttribute("district", district);
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**ORM**
Adazone.java

```
package edu.cdms.project.orm;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "adazone")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adazone.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Adazone a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adazone.findByAdaid", query = "SELECT a FROM Adazone a WHERE a.adaid = :adaid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adazone.findByAdaname", query = "SELECT a FROM Adazone a WHERE a.adaname = :adaname")})
public class Adazone implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "adaid")
    private Integer adaid;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "adaname")
    private String adaname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adaid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ailist> ailistList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adaid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<District> districtList;

    public Adazone() {
    }

    public Adazone(Integer adaid) {
        this.adaid = adaid;
    }

    public Integer getAdaid() {
        return adaid;
    }

    public void setAdaid(Integer adaid) {
        this.adaid = adaid;
    }

    public String getAdaname() {
        return adaname;
    }

    public void setAdaname(String adaname) {
        this.adaname = adaname;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Ailist> getAilistList() {
        return ailistList;
    }

    public void setAilistList(List<Ailist> ailistList) {
        this.ailistList = ailistList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<District> getDistrictList() {
        return districtList;
    }

    public void setDistrictList(List<District> districtList) {
        this.districtList = districtList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (adaid != null ? adaid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Adazone)) {
            return false;
        }
        Adazone other = (Adazone) object;
        if ((this.adaid == null && other.adaid != null) || (this.adaid != null && !this.adaid.equals(other.adaid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "edu.cdms.project.orm.Adazone[ adaid=" + adaid + " ]";
    }

}
```

District.java

```
package edu.cdms.project.orm;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "district")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "District.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM District d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "District.findByDistrictid", query = "SELECT d FROM District d WHERE d.districtid = :districtid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "District.findByDistrictname", query = "SELECT d FROM District d WHERE d.districtname = :districtname")})
public class District implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "districtid")
    private Integer districtid;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "districtname")
    private String districtname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "districtid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ailist> ailistList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "districtid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ds> dsList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "adaid", referencedColumnName = "adaid")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Adazone adaid;

    public District() {
    }

    public District(Integer districtid) {
        this.districtid = districtid;
    }

    public Integer getDistrictid() {
        return districtid;
    }

    public void setDistrictid(Integer districtid) {
        this.districtid = districtid;
    }

    public String getDistrictname() {
        return districtname;
    }

    public void setDistrictname(String districtname) {
        this.districtname = districtname;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Ailist> getAilistList() {
        return ailistList;
    }

    public void setAilistList(List<Ailist> ailistList) {
        this.ailistList = ailistList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Ds> getDsList() {
        return dsList;
    }

    public void setDsList(List<Ds> dsList) {
        this.dsList = dsList;
    }

    public Adazone getAdaid() {
        return adaid;
    }

    public void setAdaid(Adazone adaid) {
        this.adaid = adaid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (districtid != null ? districtid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof District)) {
            return false;
        }
        District other = (District) object;
        if ((this.districtid == null && other.districtid != null) || (this.districtid != null && !this.districtid.equals(other.districtid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "edu.cdms.project.orm.District[ districtid=" + districtid + " ]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your District class you have Adazone field. In your jsp page you are passing not the object but an Integer namely value="${result.adaid}"

Can you make the following changes and let me know if these worked for you.
In your jsp page pass an object and not an Integer

```
<c:forEach items="${adas}" var="result">
   <form:option value="${result}">${result.adaname}</form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

Then you have to declare two converters

```
public class IntegerToAdazone implements Converter<Integer, Adazone > {

    @Override
    public Adazone convert(Integer source) {
        Adazone a = new Adazone(source);
        return a;
    }

}

public class AdazoneToInteger implements Converter<Adazone, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convert(Adazone source) {
        return source.getId();
    }

}
```

Then you have to configure the conversion service. Have a look at the spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html (9.5.5 Configuring a ConversionService)

> A default ConversionService can convert between strings, numbers,
>   enums, collections, maps, and other common types. To supplement or
>   override the default converters with your own custom converter(s), set
>   the converters property. Property values may implement either of the
>   Converter, ConverterFactory, or GenericConverter interfaces.

```
<bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="example.IntegerToAdazone"/>
            <bean class="example.AdazoneToInteger"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Change the package above(example) as appropriate.
Hope this helps